# Reading line by line is showing AttributeError

Tags: python, file, strip

My strip() in Python is showing an error.
I copied and pasted this code from GeeksForGeeks:

```
# Python program to
# demonstrate reading files
# using for loop

L = ["Geeks\n", "for\n", "Geeks\n"]

# Writing to file
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
file1.writelines(L)
file1.close()

# Opening file
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
count = 0

# Using for loop
print("Using for loop")
for line in file1:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))

# Closing files
file1.close()
```

Turned it into this:

```
compfile = open(input('path:'), 'r')
count = 0
for line in compfile:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, 
 compfile.strip()))
compfile.close()
```

But it's showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "....", line 5, in <module>
print("Line{}: {}".format(count, compfile.strip()))
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Why did you change `line.strip()` to `compfile.strip()`? It's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be `line.strip()` not `compfile.strip()`

```
compfile = open(input('path:'), 'r')
count = 0
for line in compfile:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
compfile.close()
```

The error is because you tried using `strip()` on the file object and it doesn't have the attribute `strip`